# How to migrate relationships with full custom migration entity in CoreData

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, core-data-migration

I am currently on the verge of finishing my progressive core data migration and I am bumping into a few problems:

1) How is one expected make use of the function createRelationshipsForDestinationInstance:entityMapping:manager:error: to successfully migrate the relationships? Did Apple expect the developers to somehow know what they are querying for and re-establishing the relationships or is there a more elegant way?

2) I've noticed that the function mentioned in question 1 doesn't always get called. When I migrate from version 1 to version 2, it doesn't get called, but when I try to migrate from version 1 to version 3, it does get called. Why is that? I thought this function gets called at the end of every endInstanceCreationForEntityMapping:manager:error:?

3) I have an immediate concern with migrating many-to-many relationships as it is stored in a separate table. How does the migration manager treat this? Surely it is not another instance?

As a reference, this is the project I am experimenting all of my migration stuff on: https://github.com/sdwornik/ECD-Migration

Please feel free to fork and play around with it! :)

Answer (score 0):

1. You get the destination entity passed in.  From there you can find the source entity.  You can also use `-sourceInstancesForEntityMappingNamed: destinationInstances:`
2. Does the v1 to v2 migration work?  If it doesn't then perhaps heavy migration has broken recently.
3. It will treat all relationships the same, you need to recreate them as part of the migration.  Perhaps further details on what you believe the issue is.

### Update

> 1. I tried using that function, but was unable to fault the relationship associated with that entity. Is this a context issue?

Are you implementing the method that creates the object in the new context?  If not, why not?  If so, consider storing it in the `-userInfo` of the migration manager so you can access it later.

> 2. It works to a certain degree. It works with attribute migration, but the relationships don't get migrated.

Are the relationships being migrated?  I suspect your mapping model is doing that work for you.

> 3. So I guess I'd have to reassign each relationship every time I do custom migration?

Every relationship that your mapping model can't handle; yes.

Comment: 1. I tried using that function, but was unable to fault the relationship associated with that entity. Is this a context issue?   
2. It works to a certain degree. It works with attribute migration, but the relationships don't get migrated.  
  
3. So I guess I'd have to reassign each relationship every time I do custom migration?

Comment: You only have to do what your mapping model can't do. Only create the migration policies you need, only implement the methods you need and call super first. You don't have to migrate everything yourself, fill in the blanks.